# django | importing two models' stored data in a single html page

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I have two views in my `views.py` as following:

```
def table1(request):
    template_name = 'tables.html'
    queryset = one.objects.all()
    context = {
    "table1_list": queryset
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)

def table2(request):
    template_name = 'tables.html'
    queryset = two.objects.all()
    context = {
    "table2_list": queryset
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

and the following models in `models.py`:

```
class one(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    explanation = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)

 class two(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    explanation = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
```

In my `tables.html` I want to show the contents from both of these models. I have:

```
  <p>Table one content</p>
  <ul>
  {% for obj in table1_list %}
    {{ obj.title }}, {{ obj.explanation }}     
  {% endfor %}
 </ul>

  <p>Table two content</p>
  <ul>
  {% for obj in table1_list %}
    {{ obj.title }}, {{ obj.explanation }}     
  {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

But since I can just return one view from `views.py` in `urls.py`, I cannot return both of the tables. In `urls.py` I have to write either of the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home),
    url(r'^tables/$', table1),
]
```

or

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home),
    url(r'^tables/$', table2),
]
```

I tried adding both of the tables from the query in `views.py` as:

```
def table1(request):
    template_name = 'tables.html'
    queryset_one = one.objects.all()
    queryset_two = two.objects.all()
    context = {
    "table1_list": [queryset_one, queryset_two]
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

but just the latter table's content is shown.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do like this to show the two models in your view.

```
def table1(request):
    template_name = 'tables.html'
    queryset_one = one.objects.all()
    queryset_two = two.objects.all()
    context = {
    "table1_list": queryset_one, 
    "table2_list": queryset_two
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

then:

```
 <p>Table one content</p>
  <ul>
  {% for obj in table1_list %}
    {{ obj.title }}, {{ obj.explanation }}     
  {% endfor %}
 </ul>

  <p>Table two content</p>
  <ul>
  {% for obj in table2_list %}
    {{ obj.title }}, {{ obj.explanation }}     
  {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

Do not forget to import the two models in your `views.py`

Answer (score 1):

It may be because both classes in yout model have the same fields and django only takes the information of the latter. The way it could work is to pass both queries with different keys in a dictionary and modify your template accordigly.

So your `views.py` would look like:

```
def table1(request):
    template_name = 'tables.html'
    queryset_one = one.objects.all()
    queryset_two = two.objects.all()
    context = {
    "t1": queryset_one, "t2":queryset_two
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

And your template `tables.html` woud look like

```
  <p>Table one content</p>
  <ul>
  {% for obj in t1 %}
    {{ obj.title }}, {{ obj.explanation }}     
  {% endfor %}
 </ul>

  <p>Table two content</p>
  <ul>
  {% for obj in t2 %}
    {{ obj.title }}, {{ obj.explanation }}     
  {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```